# Use hard-coded password with PAM

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I have an application that prompts for the password of the logged in user using PAM as an authentication source. The current PAM configuration for that application reads:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
```

I would like this application to use a custom password that I would define and hard code instead of the one of the logged in user.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of importing the system's authentication mechanisms, configure [pam_userdb](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_userdb) or write a simple custom PAM module yourself. Load it as the only module in the stack:

```
auth requisite pam_userdb.so db=/etc/security/myapp.passwd.db

@include common-account
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works great.  I created the pam_userdb database file with `db_load -T -t hash myapp.passwd.db`.  Note that the `db` argument to `pam_userdb.so` must not have the `.db` suffix because it is implicitly added by PAM.

Answer (score 4):

One (probably slightly simpler) alternative is to use [pam_pwdfile](https://git.tiwe.de/libpam-pwdfile.git). It essentially allows authentication against a user-specified file, formatted like the default `/etc/passwd` file.

pam_pwdfile does not seem to be developed, but it probably just works and needs no new features. It is also available in the Debian archive, which gives it security support (if ever needed).

To use it, install it (e.g. `libpam-pwdfile` on Debian) and put a line like this in your pam config:

```
auth        required    pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/path/to/passwd_file
```

See the [README](https://git.tiwe.de/libpam-pwdfile.git/tree/README) for details.

The `/path/to/passwd` file should contain a list of usernames and hashed passwords, separated by colons, one user on each line. The hashed password can be taken from your `/etc/shadow` file, or generated with `mkpasswd` or `openssl`. E.g., to get a SHA-512-hashed password use either of these commands:

```
$ mkpasswd -m SHA-512
$ openssl passwd -6
```

An example `passwd` file could look like below. This shows a SHA-512 and descrypt hashed password:

```
  user1:$6$usgsi1RNu7wI$4rly97OA5ot5nsVSusW1jmwdjpHY7qbzGOX.E/TPfJqDuFnmMoCGVd1p1U/ew7e599QQLPnfkW0yLyuyaoAPl0
user2:NxR.0DdgI2Jnc
```

A similar alternative pam-module is [pam_fshadow](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/pam-modules/manual/html_chapter/fshadow.html), but this module does not seem packaged by Debian, so I have not investigated it further.

Comment: This is a more straight forward solution. Although I don't have the `mkpasswd` on my machine. Instead `openssl passwd -6` can be used. (`-6` is for SHA512: [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssl/passwd.1ssl.en.html))

Comment: Thanks, I've added that command to the answer!